# Convert word to a sum of integer representation of characters

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a word such as `foo` to a sum of the integer encoding of individual characters. This would be calculated as 102 + 111 + 111 equaling 324. I'm trying to achieve this using a stream from a list of characters:

```
String word = "foo";

Arrays
   .asList(word.toCharArray())
   .stream()
   .mapToInt (letter -> Character.getNumericValue(letter))
   .sum();
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
no suitable method found for getNumericValue(char[])
```

How would I go about resolving this error, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: you pass a `char[]` to `Arrays.asList(T...)`. Thus, `Arrays.asList(T...)` creates a `List<char[]>`.

Comment: `word.chars().sum()` or `word.codePoints().sum()`, depending on what you mean by character.

Comment: are you sure what `getNumericValue` is intended to do? "*The letters A-Z in their uppercase, lowercase, and full width variant forms have numeric values from 10 through 35.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the official way, and not some kind of "I want a Stream, but I can only get a Stream from a List, so I have to convert the String into a List".

```
String word = "foo";

word.codePoints().sum()
```

`String.codePoints()` returns an IntStream of the code points in the stream.
Note that not every character can be represented by a single `char`, emojis for example need two `char`s.

Comment: What is the purpose of `map(Character::getNumericValue)`?

Comment: It was in his example. If he doesn't need it, he can remove it.

Comment: Good, removed. I try to keep my examples as close to the original code while improving it (e.g. replace lambda with a method reference). I had to lookup what `getNumericValue` does. Seems like it is intended for parsing Strings to numbers with some radix.

Comment: not exactly related to some radix: "*For example, the character '\u216C' (the Roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a value of 50.*" but can (also) be used for radix > 10

Comment: When is this actually useful?

Comment: never had to use it.... probably if somehow you want to convert a hexadecimal (or some other radix) number into decimal. No idea why not use the Integer methods (`parseInt`) for that?

Comment: Thanks, Java is new to me.